# Syntax error SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server Management Studio and I don't see the syntax error here?

```
@JobNo int

AS
SELECT     
    FittingTimeSlots.dtmActualStart, Fitters.strFitterDesc, 
    Orders.lngSageInvoiceNumber, FittingTimeSlots.strScheduleType, 
    FittingTimeSlots.blnRemedial, FittingTimeSlots.intSlotNumber, 
    Orders.strCustomerName, Orders.strContactName, 
    sqs.dbo.Customers.TelOffice, Orders.strDeliveryName, 
    Orders.strDeliveryAddress1, Orders.strDeliveryAddress2, 
    Orders.strDeliveryAddressTown, Orders.strDeliveryAddressCounty, 
    Orders.strDeliveryAddressPostCode, Orders.strDeliveryAddressCountry, 
    sqs.dbo.[Quote Worktop Labels].Specification, 
    Orders.strSageCustomerOrderCode, OrderLog.strLogMemo
FROM
    Orders 
INER JOIN
    FittingItems ON Orders.lngOrderID = FittingItems.lngOrderID 
INER JOIN
    FittingTimeSlots ON FittingItems.lngScheduleItemID = FittingTimeSlots.lngScheduleItemID 
INER JOIN
    Fitters ON FittingTimeSlots.lngResourceID = Fitters.lngFitterID 
INER JOIN
    sqs.dbo.[Quote Worktop Labels] ON Orders.lngSQSQuoteID = sqs.dbo.[Quote Worktop Labels].QuoteID 
INER JOIN
    sqs.dbo.Customers ON Orders.lngCustomerID = sqs.dbo.Customers.CustomerID 
INER JOIN
    OrderLog ON OrderLog.strLogMemo = OrderLog.strLogMemo
WHERE     
    (Orders.lngSageInvoiceNumber = @Jobno)
```

I am trying to add comments (strlogmemo) to a stored procedure that creates a report (Excel)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: replace `INER`  to `INNER`

Comment: Editing questions in a way that invalidates existing answers and quite possibly even renders the whole question completely pointless is absolutely not appropriate. I rolled back that edit.

Answer (score 0):

For one, replace `INER` to `INNER`

Another... (not sure if you missed copying something)

```
@JobNo int

AS
```